# Adding Bootstrap class using @media queries not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have this simplified HTML code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="conditional-div">
                <!-- some content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS media queries :

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .conditional-div {
        addClass('container');
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .conditional-div {
        addClass('container');
    }
}
```

what I want is actually very simple, I want that `div.conditional-div` has class name `container` on medium and large device, but none on small and extra small device. but, it seems that media queries doesn't apply to medium and large device.

what did I do wrong with that media queries? thanks

Comment: Protip: `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">` is the same as `<div class="col-xs-12">`

Answer (score 1):

addClass() is JS function. You can't use it in css.

use this script in your html page.

```
<script>
    if (window.outerWidth >= 991)
    {
        $('.conditional-div').addClass('container');
    }
</script>
```